# Magento 2 & SAP B1

Tags: magento2

Within SAP B1 - a sales order can be used to create multiple invoices, each with unique identifiers.

In Magento 2 - I've been told only one order can equal one invoice.
This is going to be an issue for our current web redevelopment project - unless I can find a suitable extension for community edition.